# CSS height is 30px but in all the css there is no such value

Tags: css, joomla

I have a problem with a css in a joomla module , the site is [www.bacauacum.ro](http://www.bacauacum.ro) , the module that has this problem is "TITLURILE ZILEI" the module from the bottom of the page, it always gets the value "height : 30px" I looked in all the css and there is no such value .

Comment: It's getting set inline by one of your scripts. Probably the one that collapses and expands the div.

Comment: but why don't other modules get the same thing?

Comment: probably has something to do with it being the last module. add another module and see if that one gets the small size. its hard to tell without looking at non-minified js

Answer (score 1):

Its certainly one of the Javascript file's that's doing it - I'll see if I can find which one for you

it's in http://www.bacauacum.ro/templates/rt_mixxmag_j15/js/rokmodtools.js although I cannot narrow it down without heave decompression of the packed code there.

Comment: not sure why this is moderated down - it is in fact part of the above JS - I ran through the JS in Firebug and found it...

Comment: if give u the js above can you fix the problem?

Comment: sorry! you'll have to go back to the theme builder - they've minified it essentially turning it to garbage

Comment: isn't there any alternative solution to this , i mean , why aren't the other modules affected by this ?...

Comment: its a js problem, as everyone has pointed out. js changes the height of the div after it runs

Comment: if i delete the <div height="120" style="float:left"> from the module it works ...

Comment: the code for every news item is , </br><div class="feature-thumb"><img class="feature" width="150" height="120"src="{introimage}" border="0" alt="{title}" title="{title}" /><span style:"a color:#000"><a href="{link}">Citeste mai mult</a></span></div>
<span class="highlight-bold">{title}</span>
<p>{introtext} <a href="{link}">Citeste mai mult</a></p>

but it looks like hell , look now to see that it works

Comment: but now the problem si , how do i fix it so it looks ok

Answer (score 0):

edit the css, or the html and add the following attribute:

```
height:auto !important;
```

the value is set by one of your scripts. i cant easily tell which one, you have lots going on, and some of your scripts are minified

Comment: i noticed that the div didnt have a class or id. how did you add the above markup?

Answer (score -1):

Something's giving the element a manual style of height: 30px. I don't see it in the source; it's probably a script somewhere on the page.